# How to translate into Russian "Grow First, Clean Up Later?"

Tags: перевод

This title is from [Environment Magazine](http://www.environmentmagazine.org/Archives/Back%20Issues/May%202007/Rock-abstract.html), my version is `сначала расти, очистить позже`, but that doesn't feel good. Is there a fixed expression in Russian for that?

Comment: What does that phrase mean?

Comment: @YellowSky In context, it seems the sentence is advocating to ignore any environmental issues caused by growth until a certain level of growth has been achieved.

Comment: Эко-номика сначала, эко-логия потом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Первым делом - рост, чистота потом"

Answer (score 4):

First, even for phrases this short the literal translation could be not the best option. "Clean up" is indeed can be translated "очистить(ся)", but in Russian this verb has subtle yet noticeable differences in usage. "Сначала вырасти, а уж потом очиститься" is valid but sound slightly artificial.

"Сперва - рост, а уж потом - экологичность" is essentially  what this title is about. "Первым делом" proposes by Vadim Land is even better. "Первым делом - рост, а экологичность - потом".

Answer (score 0):

Literal translations don't seem to work well here. Here's a few options that to me sound more natural:

- "Экономика или экология?"
- "Из грязи в князи?"
- "А убирать кто будет?"

Comment: While literal translations are not solution quite often this is way too far from the original meaning.

Comment: @shabunc: It's a news magazine, in case you haven't noticed. The header was meant to sound provocative and catchy to get the reader to read on. Meaning is inferior in this case. The original "Grow first, clean up later" is a bit cryptic, you have to actually read the article to understand what it means. Thus I still insist that being intriguing and snappy and easy to read is more important for a news article header than trying to convey some obscure "meaning" or copy the original form.

Comment: @SergeySlepov, the meaning does matter here, because the magazine doesn't look like a collection of junk articles, existing only to attract readers and show them tons of ads, or to distribute malware. That's why the header should correspond to the meaning of the article in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Вали кулём - потом разберём. . .

Answer (score -1):

Сначала - рост, потом - детали.

Comment: минус потому что речь не о деталях

Answer (score -1):

"Сначала рост, затем совершенствование?"